# How to Pass ArrayList From Servlet To JSP Page?

Tags: java, jsp

here is my problem i need to pass an arrayList from servlet to the JSP

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String text = request.getParameter("text");
            ServletContext context  = getServletContext();
            context.log(text);
            StringProcess(text,context);
      response.sendRedirect("sucess.jsp");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that array list to either the sesion or request by calling setAttribute() method, like this:

```
request.setAttribute("arrName", arrObj);
```

Or

```
session.setAttribute("arrName", arrObj);
```

In your jsp page scriptlet, you can simply call `request.getAttribute("arrName")` or  `session.getAttribute("arrName")` to get that array. Mind the type casting also.

If you use the core JSTL, you can loop through the array like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${arrName}" var="tmp">
...
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Why we use request Object ??

Comment: Can We Use Response Object??

Comment: No, you simply cannot set an attribute to the response.